# How to make an asset to show dynamically in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to fix an issue with the avatar image in the header. If I use the following URL it works fine :

```
src="{{asset('user/uploads/avatars/1562309192.jpg') }}"
```

While if I try to make it dynamic and use the below, it doesn't work :

```
src="{{asset('user/uploads/avatars/{ Auth::user()->avatar}') }}"
```

Also just to mention, the below is working fine for some pages but others not. Thats why I decided to use the asset() helper.

```
src="user/uploads/avatars/{{ Auth::user()->avatar }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I hope this helpful you**

```
 src="{{asset('user/uploads/avatars/'.Auth::user()->avatar) }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it with excluding Auth::user()->avatar from the string.

```
<img src="{{ asset('user/uploads/avatars/'". Auth::user()->avatar .") }}">
```